# PHP Magic behavior of magic __get

Tags: php, magic-methods

I have a class, extended from `ArrayObject` with magic more magic:

```
class ArrayObjectMagic extends ArrayObject {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (isset($this->$method))
            return $this->$method;
        return isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : new ArrayObjectMagic();
    }
    public function __get($name) {
        return new ArrayObjectMagic();
    }
}
```

And i use this class for my `Config` class. The strange behavor is in a fact, that if `ArrayObjectMagic` obj created in `Config`, it's `__get` magic method not fires! Let me show an example:

```
$a = Config::getInstance();
var_dump(get_class($a));
var_dump($a->abcdefg());
var_dump($a->abcdefg);

var_dump("-----------");

$b = new ArrayObjectMagic();
var_dump(get_class($b));
var_dump($b->abcdefg());
var_dump($b->abcdefg);
```

it outputs:

```
string(23) "Vortex\ArrayObjectMagic"
object(Vortex\ArrayObjectMagic)#7 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
Undefined index: abcdefg
NULL

string(11) "-----------"

string(23) "Vortex\ArrayObjectMagic"
object(Vortex\ArrayObjectMagic)#8 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
object(Vortex\ArrayObjectMagic)#8 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

WHY? The only thing, what my `Config` do with `ArrayObjectMagic` is this method:

```
protected function getArrayValue($array = array()) {
        if ($this->use_array_object) {
            return new ArrayObjectMagic($array, ArrayObjectMagic::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
        } else {
            return $array;
        }
    }
```

, but somehow breaks it's `__get`.

Some kind of magic in magic...

Comment: i think the thing that brokes all magic is `ArrayObjectMagic::ARRAY_AS_PROPS` flag... but how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only return a new instance of ArrayObjectMagic.

I think you wanted something like this:

```
public function __get($name) {
    $magic = new ArrayObjectMagic();
    return $magic->$name;
}
```

Comment: no, i didn't want)
but it is also not a solution, coz as you can see, code before '-----------' works fine

Comment: Jimmy wrote a good solution.. only problem is that `new ArrayObjectMagic()` has to be in constructor __call not in get method.  __get method should simply be `return $magic->$name;` and nothing more.

Comment: oh, i got it. yep, it's a sollution!) excuse me, @jimmy-t, and a big thank you)